# xercesJ for XSD 1.1: Validator correctly processes assertions, SAXParser apparently does not

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I'm building for my java project an xml validator with
xerces-2_11_0-xml-schema-1.1-beta libraries, in order to support XSD 1.1 specific features, like assertions.

Considering this schema

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Example" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Example">

    <complexType name="NodeType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Node" type="tns:NodeType"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            </element>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="partnumber">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="string">
                    <pattern value="[A-Z0-9_\-]+"></pattern>
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
        <assert test="starts-with(@partnumber,../@partnumber)"/>
    </complexType>

    <element name="Node" type="tns:NodeType"></element>
</schema>
```

I started using the "javax.xml.validation.Validator" class

```
...
StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(new File("example.xml"));

SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1");
Schema s = sf.newSchema(new File("example.xsd"));

Validator v = s.newValidator();
v.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler())
v.validate(xmlSource)
...

private static class MyErrorHandler extends DefaultHandler {

...
        public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("Error: "); 
            System.out.println("   Public ID: "+e.getPublicId());
            System.out.println("   System ID: "+e.getSystemId());
            System.out.println("   Line number: "+e.getLineNumber());
            System.out.println("   Column number: "+e.getColumnNumber());
            System.out.println("   Message: "+e.getMessage());;
        }
...
}
```

This solution works: the assertion test in example.xsd is processed correctly and validation of xml files run smoothly (assertion tests are correctly evaluated)

Then I replaced the Validator with a SAXParser (reason: to have a better control over the sax parsing stage)

```
...
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1");
Schema s = sf.newSchema(new File("example.xsd"));

SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setSchema(s);
spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
spf.setValidating(true);
spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", true);

SAXParser parser = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader r = parser.getXMLReader();
r.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler())
r.parse("example.xml");
...
```

In this second case, the parse stage encounters an error on the xsd "assert" clause, with this message:

```
s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'NodeType' is invalid.  Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
```

If I remove the assert clause in example.xsd (thus making it 1.0 compliant) validation runs correctly, so I think the SAXParser is still working with 1.0 specifications.

Am I missing something in configuring the SAXParserFactory or the SAXParser itself in order to stick to 1.1 schema rules?

Answer (score 1):

I think the XPATH 2.0 dependecy is missing in your project. Please check it!

> XML Schema 1.1 'assertions' and 'type alternatives' require an XPath
>   2.0 processor for evaluation. For XSD 1.1 assertions, full XPath 2.0 support is required. For XSD 1.1 type alternatives, XML schema engines
>   can provide full XPath 2.0 support or they can implement a smaller
>   XPath 2.0 subset, as defined by the XSD 1.1 language.

From: 
http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html

Comment: Consider that the Validator in the same project works, and I think it leverages the same XPath processor..
So I think that dependencies are correct: my project refers the "org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor" jar bundled with the "xerces-2_11_0-xml-schema-1.1-beta" package, that I suppose contains the XPath 2.0 processor